Post Processing Bloom Issue in Vision Pro Full Immersive Mode (URP)
I am developing an application using Unity's URP for Vision Pro Full Immersive mode and have encountered an issue. When I enable the Bloom effect in Post Processing, a red area appears on the left side of the screen.
enter image description here
Here are my environment details:

Unity version: 2022.3.33f1
URP version: 14.0.11
VisionOS XR Plugin: 1.2.3

I have already tried the following methods, but the problem persists:

Updated URP and Vision Pro SDK to the latest versions.
Adjusted Bloom effect parameters.
Checked and updated graphics drivers.
Tried using the MK Glow plugin, but it did not resolve the issue.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or found a solution?
Thank you!
